# installing and implementing Angular 2 components

Tags: angular

When looking for a plugin to fill a need on my angular 2 application, my primary consideration for choosing is more often than not 'can I actually decipher how to install and use it'. If not, I'm on to the next one, which hopefully uses smaller words and larger examples.

I'm trying to implement a toggle switch on my page (not an 'on/off' toggle, but toggling between two *equivalent* states: 'Show Recent' and 'Show All').

This is one I'm looking at now. following the install instructions:
https://github.com/JulioWar/jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2

1] I've installed it using yarn (same as npm, really.)

2] Now I'm importing the CSS.

(I'm not exactly sure why, even though I've installed it, I still need to add a link to the CDN. What's the point of installing if I just link to it anyway?)

I'm pretty sure I can bypass the section on system.js.config.js since we use webpack. so:

3] It says: **You can then use the directive in your templates:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
  <bSwitch
          [switch-base-class]="baseClass"
          [switch-wrapper-class]="wrapperClass"
          [switch-label-width]="labelWidth"
          [switch-label-text]="labelText"
          [switch-off-text]="offText"
          [switch-on-text]="onText"
          [switch-on-color]="color"
          [switch-off-color]="offColor"
          [switch-size]="size"
          [switch-disabled]="disabled"
          [switch-readonly]="readonly"
          [switch-animate]="animate"
          [(ngModel)]="state"
          [switch-inverse]="inverse"
          [switch-handle-width]="handleWidth"
          [switch-base-class]="'bootstrap-switch'"
          (onChangeState)="onChange($event)">
  </bSwitch>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

I have no idea what I'm supposed to do with this. I see a somewhat similar block of code in my **app.components.ts** file:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
```

But I don't know whether this new component gets *appended outside* the existing @component or *interleaved within* it.

Comment: I'd check out the documentation on [one-way in](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#one-way-in) template syntax for Angular first. It's for one-way data binding that components and directives can use to utilize dynamic passed [@Input](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#binding-to-an-input-property) data

Comment: Sorry, I see only a single paragraph there, and I have no clue how it relates to my problem.

Comment: Do I add the new @component within the old one, or stick them next to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells you on the [page](https://github.com/JulioWar/jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2) exactly what to do. 
Add JWBootstrapSwitchModule to your list of modules imports:

```
imports: [BrowserModule, JWBootstrapSwitchModule],
```

Once its imported into your module you can use it inside any component template  under the section entited declarations inside the module that contains the import above.

```
<bSwitch [attributes]></bswitch>
```

Comment: Ah. Your example helped clarify that it was much simpler than I thought. Literally, step 3 is just "put <bSwitch></bSwitch> **in the HTML**".
It was the @Component({   selector: 'app',   template: ` that threw me.

Answer (score 0):

In the version of angular 13.3 at the moment of try to import the

imports: [BrowserModule, JWBootstrapSwitchModule],

Im getting this issue

'JwBootstrapSwitchNg2Module' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)

jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2.module.d.ts(1, 22): This likely means that the library (jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2) which declares JwBootstrapSwitchNg2Module is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.